# pentaho insert/update transformation

Tags: pentaho, transformation, jobs, insert-update

Have someone any idea why when I used `insert/update` in pentaho, it `insert/update` only with this values? [image]
The tables are in the same database. One of transformation that I have in pentaho worked with great then 1000 rows  `insert/update` but now I have so many problems with this `insert/update` because insert sometimes only 1 row per second.

Thank you!

I want to use `insert/update` in a transformation to be sure that the events I captured are update with the last version and I am expecting to `insert/update` with a higher speed in table not with 1 row per second

Answer (score 1):

The Insert/Update operator is very slow, usually is more efficient to separate the rows to insert from the rows to update, and perform the two operations separately, in two separate transformations to avoid locking the table by inserting and updating rows in two separate operations at the same time.

Comment: Indeed, This can simply be done by the "merge rows step" (compare), followed by the "synchronize after merge" (insert). It might be even more effective to only use the merge rows step, and then handle the result yourself based on the flagfield.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have the same problem with the flow....